# Run a Google Adwords campaign during particular times for multiple time zones

Tags: google-ads

Is it possible to have a Google Adwords campaign covering lots of countries and lots of different time zones, and to have ads showing only during particular times of day as per those time zones?

For example, I want the ads to display between 9am and 5pm for each time zone where I have a campaign running. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to duplicate your campaigns for each timezone, then set up a different ad schedules for each timezone that take into account the difference between the timezone set for the account.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ad Scheduling](http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=117585&from=33227&rd=1) to pick what times of the day your ad will get shown at but it seems tied to the timezone that you pick for the account, not for your website.